# MockMvc perform Basic Authentificaton Point with custom filters not calling DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-security, spring-test

I use `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`, all no-auth requests and requests, that needed authentication work perfectly (with calling DispatcherServlet)

But when I try to execute auth point (username, password) to fully test authentication:

```
var resp = mockMvc.perform(post("/api/auth")
    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestDto))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
```

After that it is processed all my custom authentication filters, create UserDetails in the auth context, but the variable resp is empty.

I try to debug (`CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` = `CustomFilter`):

```
CustomFilter.attemptAuthentication
CustomFilter.doFilter
CustomFilter.successfulAuthentication
this.successHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess
ForwardAuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess
request.getRequestDispatcher(this.forwardUrl).forward(request, response)
MockRequestDispatcher.forward
```

`MockRequestDispatcher.forward` - **this mock request dispatcher return empty response**

When I call `/api/auth` via postman instead of `MockRequestDispatcher`, It is called `ApplicationDispatcher` from apache and Its forward method call real `DispatcherServlet`

Instead of auto configurable mockMvc, I tried to use this, no effect:

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
            .addFilters(filters)
            .build();
```

When I remove addFilters, the DispatcherServlet works, but authentication not processed (filters don't calling)

Anybody knows the way how to rewrite the `MockRequestDispatcher` to the `ApplicationDispatcher` for `MockMvc` to call real DispatcherServlet and controller?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by overriding the ForwardAuthenticationSuccessHandler in auth filters:

```
@Bean
public MockMvc mockMvcWithAuthSupport(
        @Qualifier("springSecurityFilterChain") Filter springSecurityFilterChain,
        WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext
) {
    FilterChainProxy filterChain = (FilterChainProxy) springSecurityFilterChain;
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter[] filters = filterChain.getFilterChains().stream()
            .flatMap(chain -> chain.getFilters().stream())
            .filter(this::isUsernamePasswordFilter)
            .map(f -> (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter) f)
            .peek(filter -> filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new MockMvcSuccessHandler()))
            .toArray(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter[]::new);

    return MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
            .addFilters(filters)
            .build();
}
```

Custom success handler:

```
private class MockMvcSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        MockFilterChain filterChain = new MockFilterChain(mockMvc.getDispatcherServlet(), new Filter[0]);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```